# Wordpress and temporary access url

Tags: wordpress, dns

I hope everybody is well.

I have to set up a new Wordpress site, but this is the first time I need to setup the website "before" the domain name is registered.

I have webspace on shared webhosting and I can setup the Wordpress site using a temporary subdomain for my shared hosting, but this will mean setting up the Wordpress site using the temporary access url instead of the proper domain name that will be done next week.

If I setup the Wordpress site using the temporary url, once the domain name is registered, is simply changing the website address in the Wordpress General settings adequate or will I need to update the database too?

Is there a plugin that will do the above?

Thanks in advance if anyone can assist.

AH

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed and start setting up your WordPress site to start designing, ones you've completed and domain name is registered like you've said, you can:

1. Backup your File Manager files to a local storage Highlight the content, right click, and click compress then download.
2. Navigate to the root folder of the now newly registered domain(public_html), and upload the files you downloaded above.
3. Go to the `wp-config.php` file, highlight and select edit.
4. Just before a line with this words `/* That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`
   Add the lines below then save and close.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com'); 

define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

example.com is the new domain.

5. Now go back to your WordPress site to update the links. Yes, their is a plugin to update links, a lot of them but search for 'Velvet Blues Update URLs' using the plugins-> Add new.
6. After installing and activating the plugin,go to Tools -> Update urls, enter your old (subdomain) and new (root domain) URLs and in Step 2, check all options except Update All GUIDs.
7. Click the Update URLs Now button to proceed.

Check out under FaQs of your hosting provider if they've indicated a method on how users can move sites from subdomain to main domain.